# Google Maps API V3 Tiles Not Rendering - Whats the Deal?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a map that has a very zoomed in view, with a height of about 8500px and width of only about 400px.  When the map loads, some of the top and bottom tiles do not show.  If, after the map loads, I zoom out, and back in, it will display, but there are still issues with rendering things like labels and markers on the top and bottom sections.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xdu1vmg/) that recreates the problem (scroll down in the results) as well as the js for my map initialize function:

```
function initialize() {
var myStyles = [
    { featureType: "poi",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" },
                ]
    },
    { featureType: "transit",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off"},
                ]
    }
];
var center = {lat: 33.7251470, lng: -118.2879740};
var mapOptions = {
    center: center,
    zoom: 18,
    zoomControl: true,
    panControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    styles: myStyles,
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue of the experimental API-version, load the release-version instead:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=yourkey&callback=initialize
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n99hLwf5/