# Google Maps API glitch on large screen

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a google map displayed as a full width banner using the google maps javascript api
When navigating the map I often see some parts not being rendered until I reach some point
It seems to happen only on large screen > 2000px (2500px in my case)

You can see the glitch happening here : https://codepen.io/DamienGR/pen/poEgMdN (I've removed my api key but it does the same thing with or without the api key)
In this example, when I navigate to the east, I always see a grey box about 300px after reaching "Ukraine". The missing part is displayed only if I keep navigating (but never loads if I stop there)

I've made a gif so you can see it in case your screen is not large enough to reproduce :

[image: google maps glitch]

The code :

```html
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

    <script>
    function initMap() {
      var mapOpts = {
          center: {lat: 50.46222396587356, lng: -30.968595685134837},
          zoom: 6,
      };
      
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOpts);
    }
    </script>
```

Any idea how I can this fix ?
Thank you !

Comment: Sounds similar to this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150203085.

Comment: I just found a similar issue which is 5 years old and unresolved :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265283/google-maps-api-v3-tiles-not-rendering-whats-the-deal

Comment: I ended up moving to leaflet with mapbox layer and it's smoother